# Error when using two variables in a for statement

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50, declare

```
for (int a = 0, int x = 1; a < 2; a++, x++)
{
  // Body
}
```

When I do this, it shows me an error on that line at the part when I declare x.

The error is:

```
error: expected identifier or '('
        for (int a = 0, int x = 1; a < 2 && x < 3; a++, x++)
```

Please note that this was the first time I ever declared `x`.

This problem is related to cs50's filter.

I tried googling to see if the code itself was incorrect but all the example were like mine.

I tried replacing the `,` with `;` but that just made another error saying it was expecting an expression at the very same place.

I also tried remove the `int` from `x` and declaring it at the start of the function but that also was an error saying it was shadowing a local variable.

Comment: Since they are both `int`s you can use: `for (int a = 0, x = 1;   ...`.

Comment: `int a = 0, int x = 1;` is not valid syntax. Take it out of the `for` loop and look at it and it'll probably become clear.

Comment: Please show an example on the web where where you have found an example like yours.

Comment: OT: why don't you get rid of `x` and use `(a + 1)` instead? And note that the error message wasn't from the code you gave: the end conditional is different.

Comment: I would avoid it. Write it more humans readable way

Answer (score 4):

A `for` loop is a convenience construct around the more basic `while` loop to help programmers associate the variables being used and to constrain the scope of those used in the initializer clause. The initializer clause needs to be a valid initializer statment (or empty). Multiple definitions with type specifications separated by a comma is not a valid init statement.

```c
int a = 0, int x = 1;
```

would need to be

```c
int a = 0, x = 1;
```

And if variables with different types would be needed, you could use a `while` loop:

```
{ // scope limiter
    int a = 0;
    double x = 1.0;
    while(a < 2) {
        // Body
        ++a;
        ++x;
    }
}
```

... or a combination of the two:

```c
{ // scope limiter
    double x = 1.0;
    for(int a = 0; a < 2; ++a, ++x) {
        // Body
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
for (int a = 0, x = 1; a < 2; a++, x++)
```

If you want multiple variables of different type, declare them before the loop.